# Is it possible to get a partial file with the open function?

Tags: python, azure, azure-cognitive-services

I need to send a PDF for reading with Microsoft Azure. I only need to decode the first page of long documents. I'm trying to send only the first page. Here's how it currently works:

```
from azure.cognitiveservices.vision.computervision import ComputerVisionClient
from msrest.authentication import CognitiveServicesCredentials

subscription_key = "my_key387309823"
endpoint = "my_endpoint82309483098420"

computervision_client = ComputerVisionClient(endpoint, CognitiveServicesCredentials(subscription_key))
```

Here's what I'm trying to change:

```
computervision_client.read_in_stream(open('mydocument.pdf', 'rb'), raw=True, pages=['1'])
```

This sends the entire PDF to Azure. Is it possible to cut the first page of the PDF with the `open` function? It should be easy with `open().read().split()` but that's not the format I can send Azure.

Comment: There are several third-party libraries for working with PDF files in Python that may be able to help you, try looking into [PyMuPDF](https://pymupdf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial.html) (formerly known as `fitz`) or [PyPDF](https://pythonhosted.org/PyPDF2/index.html). Using the built-in `open` method just gives you a file obj/bytestream to work with, and vanilla Python doesn't have any context for working with PDF file format.

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not possible with the `open` function. You need to use any of the PDF python modules to extract only the first page of your PDF and   get the byte stream of that 1 page PDF, which then you can pass it to the computervision module.